# Need to repair leaky hose bibb

Tags: plumbing, faucet, hose

My hose bibb drips out of the faucet. I want to fix it. I know I need to replace the washer but I can't figure out how to take it apart! Has anyone seen a hose bibb like this and do you know what to do? I tried removing the little circular cover on the front of the handle but there is nothing behind it but the hole the screw went into.
[image]

Comment: I believe you'll need to pull the plastic handle straight off after removing the screw. It will probably be brittle and may break. At that point more of the mechanism will be exposed and there should be other things to unscrew.

Comment: After removing the screw, try some WD40 or another penetrating spray around the back side of the handle. That might help loosen it.

Comment: If that screw holding the handle is a straight slot , um heat that will destroy the handle may work if it is a hex / slot try turning CW  and  CCW with earth turn slightly more CCW until it releases ,,, it may take heat.

Comment: @EdBeal they got the screw out once already, but could not see how to proceed.

Comment: That's a frost-free hose bibb. Here is a good start https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlvE0QeRots or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlDZyKpwFV4

Comment: I would personally just replace the entire bibb but I do understand that not everyone is comfortable with such a task.